# Finding dead code in Android apk

Tags: java, android, proguard, dead-code

I'm trying to find dead code in .apk file for some analysis. For this, I'm using dex2jar on classes.dex file and then trying to use Proguard to detect dead code. But Proguard fails to run giving error that it can't find some dynamically referenced classes. Also, it gives a bunch of Warnings saying the referenced class not found. Need help on how to resolve this. Also, can I find dead code using Proguard this way ? If not, what others options should I explore ?

Answer (score -1):

Surely you can use Proguard to find dead code. Look [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#deadcode).

Comment: I know that we can use Proguard but it is giving Error when used with jar created by dex2jar (read the question again)